# How to refer to route name with FOSRestBundle

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

Candidate Controller

```
class DefaultController extends PreviewMeController
{

    /**
     * Complete registration process for candidate
     *
     * @ApiDoc(
     *     section="Candidate",
     *     tags={"common"},
     * )
     *
     * @Rest\View()
     * @Post("/ua/register/candidate/{token}")
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \FOS\RestBundle\View\View
     */
    public function registerCandidateAction($token)
    {

    }

}
```

Candidate routing.yml

```
candidate_api_routes:
    type: rest
    prefix: /v1
    resource: "CandidateBundle\Controller\DefaultController"
    name_prefix: "api_1_c_"
```

AppBundle Controller

```
/**
     * Register a new user on the website
     *
     * @ApiDoc(
     *     section="Common Functionalities",
     *     tags={"common"},
     *     requirements={
     *          {"name"="email", "dataType"="string", "description"="Email of user"},
     *          {"name"="username", "dataType"="string", "description"="Username. Keep this same as email address"},
     *          {"name"="first_name", "dataType"="string", "description"="First name of user"},
     *          {"name"="last_name", "dataType"="string", "description"="Last name of user"},
     *          {"name"="plainPassword", "dataType"="array", "requirement"="['first':'password','second':'password']", "description"="Plain password. Send as an array with 'first' and 'second' as array keys"},
     *          {"name"="user_type","dataType"="string","requirement"="employer|candidate","description"="Employer or candidate user type"}
     *     },
     *     statusCodes={
     *          200 = "When user is successfully registered",
     *          400="When there is a validation error in the registration process"
     *     }
     * )
     * @Post("/ua/register")
     * @Rest\View()
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return array|\FOS\RestBundle\View\View
     */
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
        /** @var UserManager $fos_userManager */
        $fos_userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $fos_userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);
        $user->setUserType($request->request->get('user_type'));
        //remove user_type from request so it's not forwarded to form
        $request->request->remove('user_type');

        $form = $formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        $form->submit($request->request->all());

        if( $form->isValid() ){

            $event = new UserEvent($user);
            $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
            $dispatcher->dispatch(PmEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

            $fos_userManager->updateUser($user);

            $wrapper = new PMResponseWrapper();
            $wrapper->setData(array(
                'ob_key' => $user->getObKey()
            ));

            /** @var View $response */
            $response = View::create($wrapper->getFormattedData());
            $response->setLocation( $this->generateUrl('register_candidate') );

            return $response;
        }

        return $this->view($form);

    }
```

app/console debug:router dump

```
  api_1_register                 POST       ANY      ANY    /api/v1/ua/register
  api_1_register_confirm_token   POST       ANY      ANY    /api/v1/ua/register/confirm_token/{token}
  api_1_c_index                  GET        ANY      ANY    /api/v1/index
  api_1_c_register_candidate     POST       ANY      ANY    /api/v1/ua/register/candidate/{token}
```

Problem is even though `registerCandidateAction` shows up in `debug:router`, I am not able to call it with `$this->generateUrl()` in `registerAction`.

When I call this line `$response->setNextUrl($this->generateUrl('register_candidate'));` I get this error `Unable to generate a URL for the named route \"register_candidate\" as such route does not exist.`

Please help in finding what's wrong here.

Comment: The generated route name is api_1_c_register_candidate not register_candidate - if it doesn't exist in router:debug then you *can't* use it with generateUrl. Because you specified api_1_c_ for name_prefix, that's the route. If you don't want that, remove it.

Comment: Thanks @Richard if I use api_1_c_register_candidate how will the versioning work? What if I need to release a new version of the same controller with api_2 then I change everywhere manually?

Comment: No problem. Please read the versioning docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/versioning.html this should help.

Comment: Just adding that the route name and the URI can be controlled independently in fosrestbundle. So if you want you can keep the same route name, but change the underlying URI if you wanted to force a version change, for example.

Comment: Thanks mate..didn't know about that.

Comment: @Richard do you know any way by which PhpStorm can detect that? It's not picking up the route names.

Comment: That's up to the symfony2 extension which you're presumably using. it's not bad but it doesn't resolve absolutely everything.